# can't preserve markers in google maps v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

```
function showPointMarker (point, index, address, changeCenter, changeZoomLevel) {

    if (changeCenter)
    {
        if (changeZoomLevel) {
        //  marker.setMap(map);
            map = new google.maps.Map(
                      document.getElementById('map'), {
                      center: point,
                      zoom: 7,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    });
        } else {
            map = new google.maps.Map(
                      document.getElementById('map'), {
                      center: point,
                      zoom: 10,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    });


        var letter = String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + index);
        //var letteredIcon = new GIcon(baseIcon);
        //letteredIcon.image = "";
        var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker" + letter + ".png" ,
                new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(point.hb,point.ib);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon:pinImage,
            html: address
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            //  alert(this.html);
              infowindow.setContent(this.html);
              infowindow.open(map, this);
          });

        } //else ends here
    } // if change center ends here

} //function ends here
```

I m trying to add markers to the map, i can't preserve my previous markers,im only seeing the last, please help me out here.. Appreciate your help.
I am missing something here, can any one point my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are reinitializing the map every time. You only want to do these operations once, like:

```
if( ! map ) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(        
    // ...
```

Make map a global var that starts as null.

```
var map = null;
```

Also, if you are refreshing the page, you'll need to redraw all the points in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried that, now am getting the frist and the last markers on the map..

Comment: The line `if ( changeCenter )` looks curious.  It wraps the entire function, so if this is false, the function doesn't do anything.  If this is the case why call the function?   I might try taking this out (perform this test in the block that calls this function).  Also the the first `if ( changeZoomLevel) ' and `} else {'  Looks a bit asymmetrical.   I'd split out all map initialization  and special cases out of this function, and I'd remove everything related to changeCenter and changeZoomLevel.   Also I'd check for javascript errors in case it's just stopping on these.

Comment: Thanks User1389596, I took out all both the if conditions , its working fine now.., i think the latest maps will check for the zoom level change or centerchange automatically, correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: If needed you can add listeners for zoom/pan in the map initialization.  It only needs to register the callbacks once.